# Convert string to json support function

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this string

```
const str = `{
  a: 444,
  b: function () {
    return 44
  }
}`
```

into an object. How can I do that?

```
{
  a: 444,
  b: function () {
    return 44
  }
}
```

Comment: `eval(str)`, ```new Function(`return ${str}`)()```, basically any way that lets you evaluate JavaScript dynamically.

Comment: @Habib   whats about JSON.parse(yourString) !!

Comment: @mir OP only has a JSON-like string (and it's not even much like it, it's really just the source code of a JS object), it has a function within it.  Using `eval` or `new Function` is the correct route, as Felix suggested.  You have to _really_ trust the source of your string though.

Comment: @JamesThorpe thank you

Comment: @FelixKling Could you provide an example? I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @HabibRohman http://jsfiddle.net/qAcDe/

Comment: `new Function(`return ${str}`)()` works for me. Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, if you wanted to use eval, you have to actually wrap the string into parenthesis, otherwise it's interperted as a block: ```eval(`(${str})`)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FelixKling commented, you can evaluate dinamically any string using something like:

```js
const str = `{
  a: 444,
  b: function () {
    return 44
  }
}`
var objGenerator=new Function(`return ${str};`)
var objStr=objGenerator();

console.log(objStr.b());
console.log(objGenerator);
```

I want to remark that `str` **is not** JSON, because a JSON string must use double quotes to declare attributes and it cannot define functions:

```js
    var validJson=`{ 
        "a": 444,
        "b": "Some string, it could be a function declaration to be evaluated"
    }`
    
    var objFromJson=JSON.parse(validJson);
    
    console.log(objFromJson.b)
```

Answer (score -2):

JSON.stringify(obj{}) converts Json => String

JSON.parse(string) converts string => Json

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: `JSON.parse` not support function as their value

Comment: I believe you are confusing JSON with JavaScript objects. `JSON.stringify` generates JSON, `JSON.parse` converts JSON into native JS values.